# ScrollTop with height 100% elements

Tags: jquery, css, smooth-scrolling

I have a problem guys where I have a single page site, with height 100% elements (so it fits the fold) and i have about 4 of these sections stacked. There is a nav with a anchors that link to relevant sections. I want these to smooth scroll, but for some reason the offset().top returns 0 no matter the element... Is there a way to smooth scroll these? I have tried 3 different libraries, all the same result. As a side note, optimization still needs to accor.

Live version: http://jackaroocaravans.com.au/new/

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted your code...

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice Please check link provided, as code base is simple too big to post.

Comment: Almost impossible to see what you've done due to minified code. We're not gonna trawl the code for it. Please pull out methods you use for scrolling.

Comment: You can't seriously be expecting people to pull apart your minified code.  Remember you're the one wanting help here, the least you can do is provide people with the resources they need to help you.

Comment: Guys... That is a fair point, but what more do you want? Like with Google Chrome you have the beautification as part of the developer tools, and the area's I believe the problem to occur resides inside the html or body css tags or maybe one of the section tags, as for js, a simple beautification and you've got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works fine for me on your page (for example, for scrolling to the interior section)

```
jQuery('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: jQuery("#interior").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

To bind to anchor tag click events:

```
jQuery('a[href^="#"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(jQuery(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Will this require me to wrap the entire page in an #interior div?

Comment: @MaraisRossouw No. This code is for scrolling to the already-existing `<section id="interior">`

Comment: Right, so just with a simple $(a[href^="#"]).each(function() { .. }); I can get all those links working yeah?

Comment: @MaraisRossouw I added code for binding to the links' click events. Your jQuery appears to be in noConflict mode and `$` isn't defined in the global scope (but maybe you're defining it in a local scope somewhere)

Comment: Yeah, I use Google Closure Compiler, along with a couple of other things to make it not so open. Its a self calling function `(function($) { .. })(jQuery)`.

Comment: @MaraisRossouw I believe you may have to wrap everything in an `overflow: auto;` div instead of setting `overflow: auto;` on the body to make it work in Chrome after all. Of course, if you do that make sure you replace `'html, body'` with the ID of the wrapper div.